# Do all inflation swaps reference the non-seasonally-adjusted index values?

Tags: swaps, inflation

Inflation CPI values (typically published monthly except Australia) are typically published in both SA (sseaonally adjusted) and NSA (non-seasonally adjusted) variants.

Inflation swaps reference the change in a CPI index between issue date and maturity date.

From those I've seen so far, inflation swaps reference the NSA variant.

Is this always the case?

Answer (score 1):

BBG index references for inflation swaps (via JPM paper); you can check if NSA.

- EU - CPTFEMU
- FR - FRCPXTOB
- IT - ITCPIUNR
- ES - SPIPC
- DE - GRCP2000
- NL - NECPIND
- GB - UKRPI
- SE - SWCPI
- JP - JCPNGENF
- AU - AUCPI
- US - CPURNSA

Comment: Could you kindly share the link or name of the JPM paper?